# After local storage, I cannot change the value or delete the existing key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, local-storage

After local storage, I cannot change the value or delete the existing key

```js
        var myMap = new Map();
    myMap.set('0', 'foo');
    myMap.set(1, 'bar');


localStorage.mymap = JSON.stringify(Array.from(myMap.entries()));  //I save to localstorage
var groups = new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.mymap ));   //I get it from the localstorage

 groups.set('0', 'bar'); // this does not work
 groups.delete('0'); // this does not work

groups.set('2', 'bar'); //it works!
groups.delete('2'); // it works!
```

How to remove and modify a Map item after localstorage?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Keep in mind that your modifications after building the Map from localStorage are changing `groups` and not the value in localStorage. What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: “This does not work” is not helpful for people helping you. You need to explain the *expected* behaviour and the *actual* behaviour you are getting that leads you to believe it does not work.